# .text() jQuery method not updating text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have dates on top of a div that I want changed on a page refresh, or when updated using the calendar. The dates don't update to todays date on opening the page, and don't change when selecting a different date using the calendar. Here is the code for reference:

**HTML**

```
<div id="date-picker-dates">
          <div id="date-picker-date-first" class="date-picker-date">
            04/23/2017
          </div>
          <div id="date-picker-date-second" class="date-picker-date">
            05/23/2017
          </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
var datesBoxes = $(".date-picker-date");
console.log(datesBoxes[0]);

...

// set up dates
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...

  $(datesBoxes[0]).text(getDateString(dates[0]));
  $(datesBoxes[1]).text(getDateString(dates[1]));

});

...

function updateDateShown() {
  var formattedDate = getDateString(dates[currentDate]);
  var updateDateBox = $(datesBoxes[currentDate]);

  updateDateBox.text(formattedDate);
}
```

After a lot of console.log's, I found that the issue is in initializing datesBoxes. The console.log beneath it should return

```
<div id="date-picker-date-first" class="date-picker-date">
  04/23/2017
</div>
```

but returns

```
undefined
```

instead.

**NOTE: I followed this calendar on CodePen since I am relatively new to WebDev. For reference - https://codepen.io/samwooly/pen/eyBmKz**

Comment: Because your document hasn't loaded the elements yet. Move all code into $(document).ready

Comment: @xstaticvoidx This worked thank you so much! I had multiple $(document).ready's, though, so I just put it in the first one where it seemed most relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines are being executed before the document has loaded. Move them into your `$(document).ready` function:

```
var datesBoxes = $(".date-picker-date");
console.log(datesBoxes[0]);
```

Additionally, `datesBoxes` is an array that takes an integer as an index (`dateBoxes[0]`). I'm not sure what `currentDate` is, but make sure it's an index (0, 1, 2...) and not a date.

Comment: currentDate was an index; all I had to do was move the initialization into the $(document).ready function. Thank you!